# directInput обновление списка устройств подключенных к ПК

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

Проблема следующая:
Есть код, инициализирующий direct input и получающий список устройств для дальнейшего использования:

```
CComPtr<IDirectInput> dInput;
HRESULT hr = -1;

hr = DirectInput8Create(GetModuleHandle(NULL), DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IID_IDirectInput8, (void**)&dInput, NULL);
if (hr != DI_OK)
{
    return false;
}

CComPtr<IDirectInputJoyConfig8> device_config;
hr = dInput->QueryInterface(IID_IDirectInputJoyConfig8, (void**)&device_config);
if (hr != DI_OK)
{
    return false;
}
unsigned int number = 0;
DIJOYCONFIG preferredCfg = {0};
preferredCfg.dwSize = sizeof (preferredCfg); // Тут точка остановки

while (true)
{
    hr = device_config->GetConfig(number++, &preferredCfg, DIJC_GUIDINSTANCE);

    if (hr == DI_OK)
    {
        // Конфигурирование и сохранения устройства для дальнейшего использования
    }
    else
    if (hr == DIERR_NOMOREITEMS)
        break;
    else
    if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
        continue;
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Если в дебаге стать в точке остановки, подключить геймпад и продолжить перечисление устройств, то программа не видит свежеподключенный геймпад.

Удаление/освобождение/пересоздание интерфейсов direct input не помогает. Такое чувство, что при первом вызове где-то это сохраняется в кэш, но как его очистить я не понимаю.

Что надо сделать, чтобы программа увидела устройства подключенные после вызова DirectInput8Create / QueryInterface?

<del>**Upd Solution:**
Ларчик просто открывался.
Добавляем реинициализацию ком перед вызовом `DirectInput8Create`

    CoUninitialize();
    CoInitialize(nullptr);

И устройства обновляются, надеюсь реинициализация не затронет существующие и использующиеся ком-объекты в других классах, может кто-либо это подтвердить?</del>

Update 2:
Ларчик открывался чуть сложнее, оказалось устройства надо перечислять:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumJoysticksCallback(const DIDEVICEINSTANCE* pdidInstance, void* param) 
{ 
    // Enumerate through all devices, we will check them later
    return DIENUM_CONTINUE;
}

// Enum devices
hr = dInput->EnumDevices(DI8DEVCLASS_GAMECTRL, EnumJoysticksCallback, nullptr, DIEDFL_ATTACHEDONLY); 
if (hr != DI_OK)
{
    return false;
}
```

В Функции-перечислителе можно сохранить устройства куда-либо для дальнейшего использования, но в моем случае это производится позже, вместе с проверкой конфигурации и предустановкой значений вывода. Однако само перечисление неведомым образом обновляет список устройств где-то в недрах ком-объектов и уже конфиги видят реальное количество устройств

Comment: Пересоздание интерфейсов и не поможет, надо сам объект пересоздать. Получение интерфейса никак не влияет на COM объект, точно так же dynamic_cast указателя никак не влияет на сам экземпляр класса. Нужен новый `CoCreateInstance`, да и то не факт. Если объект глобальный, он все равно может кешироваться. Сразу скажу, что это все общие соображения, сам дела с DirectX не имел.

Comment: стоит учитывать, что API DirectInput устарело, ему уже почти 20 лет

Comment: @VTT, а что есть на замену?

Comment: XInput, raw input

Comment: @VTT, xInput - слишком много орграничений, фиг с ними с 4мя устройствами на шине, но он не поддерживает многие модели геймпадов и HID devices(что критично в данном случае), raw input спасибо, буду читать)

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал использовать SDL для работы с gemapad устройствами.